# jQuery search filter show the list item header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have following list

```
<ul id="fromList">
    <li class="header">-ABC-</li>
    <li class="item">123</li>
    <li class="item">258</li>
    <li class="item">189</li>
    <li class="item">545</li>

    <li class="header">-CDE-</li>
    <li class="item">789</li>
    <li class="item">215</li>
    <li class="item">897</li>
    <li class="item">999</li>

    <li class="header">-EFG-</li>
    <li class="item">701</li>
    <li class="item">566</li>
    <li class="item">511</li>       
</ul>
```

When searching the item it should show the list item header
For example when i am searching '9'
It should show

- -ABC-
- 189
- -CDE-
- 789
- 897
- 999

Now I am getting search list only:

```js
function filter(element) {
  var value = $(element).val();
  $("#fromList li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(value, "i")) > -1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txtList' onkeyup="filter(this)" />
<ul id="fromList">
  <li class="header">ABC</li>
  <li class="item">123</li>
  <li class="item">258</li>
  <li class="item">189</li>
  <li class="item">545</li>

  <li class="header">CDE</li>
  <li class="item">789</li>
  <li class="item">215</li>
  <li class="item">897</li>
  <li class="item">999</li>

  <li class="header">E</li>
  <li class="item">701</li>
  <li class="item">566</li>
  <li class="item">511</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could combine the [`.prevAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) with the [`.first()` method](http://api.jquery.com/first/) in order to select the header element of the `li` that should be shown:

```
$(this).prevAll('.header').first().show();
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/r41xbtvh/)

```
function filter(element) {
    var value = $(element).val();
    $("#fromList li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
            $(this).prevAll('.header').first().show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

---

I'd suggest using [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). I also shortened your code a little.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/d9qtvw0z/)

```
$('#txtList').on('keyup', function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $('#fromList li').hide().each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) {
            $(this).prevAll('.header').first().add(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

As a side note, if you want to exclude the header from being selected if you were to type something like "ABC", just use the `.not()` method to negate the `.header` element from the selection:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLjv6u2c/)

```
if ($(this).not('.header').text().search(value) > -1) {
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could just specify sorting the list items with the `items` class, rather than every item in the list:

```
$('#txtList').keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $('#fromList li.item').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```